# Problems with react-native-svg-transformer and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I decided to add typescript in a existing project and have a issue when a i works with import of .svg like a this

```
import Icon from "../../../assets/Icon.svg";
```

i tried configure metro.config.js

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"],
    },
  };
})();
```

and add a declarations file

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  import React from "react";
  import { SvgProps } from "react-native-svg";

  const content: React.FC<SvgProps>;
  export default content;
}
```

but it's not work for me, and i get the error

[image: in the terminal]

[image: in the phone]

Comment: Do you able to fit it? I am also experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I am still having this error. Any solution for that?